# Cannot add Google's "NearbyMessages" Cocoapod to Kotlin/Native project

Tags: ios, kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I wonder if anyone can help me to add a cocoapod to a kotlin native module, not having much luck so far! The library is Google's NearbyMessages API.
https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/get-started

So far I have:

1. Cloned the KMM with cocoapods sample app. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-with-cocoapods-sample. (change the kotlin plugin version numbers to 1.4.21 since the snapshots referenced in the sample dont seem to be available anymore)
2. Gradle sync and build the project. Everything succeeds.
3. Add the NearbyMessages pod in build.gradle.kts just above the AFNetworking line...  `pod("NearbyMessages")`
4. Now when I gradle sync I get the following error.

```
> Task :kotlin-library:cinteropNearbyMessagesIosArm64 FAILED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: /var/folders/t7/gwvnk41x66g5kmr7s7y8thdw0000gn/T/6648793494349780018.m:1:9: fatal error: module 'NearbyMessages' not found
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.UtilsKt.ensureNoCompileErrors(Utils.kt:152)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesASTFiles(ModuleSupport.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesInfo(ModuleSupport.kt:14)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.buildNativeLibrary(main.kt:507)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.processCLib(main.kt:265)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.interop(main.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.InteropCompilerKt.invokeInterop(InteropCompiler.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.mainImpl(main.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.main(main.kt:41)
Execution failed for task ':kotlin-library:cinteropNearbyMessagesIosArm64'.
> Process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I was able to install the cocoapod using a podfile and pod install. With no KMM involved. I've tried all sorts of random stuff besides but these are the steps that seem like they should work.

Here is the podspec file for NearbyMessages:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/f/b/9/NearbyMessages/1.1.1/NearbyMessages.podspec.json

Comment: It seems somethiing like that https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43512. You can file an issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com) for JB's help.

Comment: You have your answer here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JB guys have answered you [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44155).

I report the answer here for better indexing:

> Hello, Tom Pratt, thank you for the report! As far as I can see, the
> problem is caused by the fact `NearbyMessages` pod consists of a static
> Objective-C library, not a framework. It has no module.modulemap, so
> the cinterop cannot interpret it correctly. Changing
> `build/cocoapods/defs/NearbyMessages.def`'s content to have a headers
> option instead of module let me execute `cinterop` manually, but I'm not
> sure it can be done inside of the Cocoapods Integration.

As a manual workaround they suggests:

> Also, to make this manual workaround a bit more usable, you can try to
> tune the Gradle task generating this `.def` file. Just add

```
tasks.named<DefFileTask>("generateDefNearbyMessages").configure {
    doLast {
        outputFile.writeText("""
            language = Objective-C
            headers = GNSMessages.h
        """)
    }
}
```